# Releasing thread memory

Tags: c, multithreading, solaris

When creating a thread, it is allocated its own storage for local variables, etc. When or how is this released back to memory for re-use: when the thread ends?

When a thread tries to allocate a dynamic storage, is it still stored in the thread's local storage or is it stored in a global storage?

Answer (score 2):

The local storage for thread is from stack, so you don't need to release it. just end thread is ok.

And dynamic storage is from heap, so you must release the allocated memory.

Answer (score 0):

Remember - there's also ["thread local storage"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage) (aka "TLS").  This independent of either heap storage ("new" or "malloc()") or local variables.  Like heap storage, your application will explicitly allocate TLS and explicitly free it.

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends.  If the thread is detached, you don't need to clean up the thread's resources when the thread ends.  If the thread isn't detached you *may* (I'm not sure about the Solaris specifics) need to call pthread_join or something like that to clean up the thread's resources.  Of course, you'll need to clean up TLS and dynamic storage.

Comment: Can you provide a reference to support that answer?

Comment: See [pthread_join](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/pthread_join.html), especially the Rationale section paragraph 2 which says "After the thread terminates, the application may then choose to clean up resources ... For instance, after pthread_join() returns, any application-provided stack storage could be reclaimed." One way to test this on a particular implementation would be to fire up a bunch of threads in non-detached state and look at what kind of memory resources they use.  Repeat with detached threads.  If there's a difference in usage, I guess it matters.

Comment: @Idav1s: Interesting - that's different to what I see on the mac, clearly one needs to re-read all these documents on the Solaris.

Answer (score 0):

Threads allocate local storage on the stack for function data, or in a special TLS (Thread local storage) for thread-local globals.  Anything allocated by the thread on the heap remains until explicitly free()d.